# IIS7 Settings File Locations

Tags: iis-7

Where does IIS7 saves its configuration for each virtual directory/ application and its physical path?

Is it an XML file? And if so, will editing this XML file affect the IIS configuration (after restarting)?

Comment: http://www.iis.net/configreference

Answer (score 166, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `applicationHost.config`, which is located in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`.

Yes, it's an XML file, and yes, editing the file by hand will affect the IIS config after a restart. You can think of IIS Manager as a GUI front-end for editing `applicationHost.config` and `web.config`.

Comment: Is the file is locked ? ( while runnning ?) Can I edit it without any un-lock's ?

Comment: No, it's not locked. You might want to make a copy before you make any edits, though.

Comment: Also the file might not display the actual info for non-admin access as explained [in this question and a comment to an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637268/iis-7-5-app-pool-not-in-applicationhost-config)

Comment: By restart, it needs a full windows reboot not just IISRESET

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 doesn't appear to require a restart, at least when adding new application pools and web sites.

Answer (score 55):

Also check this answer from here: [Cannot manually edit applicationhost.config](http://www.cosnetics.co.uk/articles/cannot-manually-edit-applicationhost.config/)

> The answer is simple, if not that obvious: win2008 is 64bit, notepad++
>   is 32bit. When you navigate to Windows\System32\inetsrv\config using
>   explorer you are using a 64bit program to find the file. When you open
>   the file using using notepad++ you are trying to open it using a 32bit
>   program. The confusion occurs because, rather than telling you that
>   this is what you are doing, windows allows you to open the file but
>   when you save it the file's path is transparently mapped to
>   Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config.
>
> So in practice what happens is you open applicationhost.config using
>   notepad++, make a change, save the file; but rather than overwriting
>   the original you are saving a 32bit copy of it in
>   Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config, therefore you are not making changes
>   to the version that is actually used by IIS. If you navigate to the
>   Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config you will find the file you just saved.
>
> How to get around this? Simple - use a 64bit text editor, such as the
>   normal notepad that ships with windows.

Comment: Another approach is to use the administrative c$ to allow 32 bit programs to read\write as if they were 64 bit since the windows file share service is 64 bit:  `\\yourservername\c$\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`

Comment: You can also use the info from @TimLewis and use your machine name if it's your local machine that you want to edit with a 32-bit editor.

Comment: Just wanted to note that Notepad++ is fully 64bit for a while now.