# one or more threads of w3wp.exe are waiting to finish network I/O

Tags: iis, freeze, w3wp.exe

I'm currently experiencing some hangs on production environmen of our web application server and after some investigation I'm not seeing too much request queued up in the worker process of the Application Pool just normall one may be 10 or 15 , the state of most of this request is ExexuteRequestHandler , when i monitor w3wp.exe in Resource monitor and right click it and choose Analyze wait chain , i found i got the atatched error message "one or more threads of w3wp.exe are waiting to finish network I/O"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuJeJ.png)

and in this point the system become very slow and i have to end process of the hanging w3pw.exe to make it normal again, but this issue happen like 4 times daily.

any help please where to check

I followed the instrcutions in this issue but withour any resulte

[How prevent CPU usage 100% because of worker process in iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992383/how-prevent-cpu-usage-100-because-of-worker-process-in-iis)

Comment: Actually "the state of most of this request is ExexuteRequestHandler" matches the problem you described and an experienced engineer can debug further into that and learn what might be the cause. The "one or more threads of w3wp.exe are waiting to finish network I/O" part can be irrelevant at least for now. I don't expect any beginners can find out the right way to move further (with profiler or windbg), so either escalate to a more senior guy in your team with that skill or open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Does this also happen on debugging environment?

Comment: @Jerry right now we don't have debugging environment

Comment: @LexLi Ok will check