# How to Lock IIS configuration Setting

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-7, server, iis-7.5

Currently, we are using IIS 7.0. We don't want to allow people change on IIS websites like creations or modification. Is there any way to lock applicationHost.config so that we are not going to changes

Comment: Only administrators can change that file in all possible ways by default. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Refer this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635884/iis7-settings-file-locations) . This may help you .